# Can we start a competition for chess.se?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have seen several beta and other se sites were launching competitions and I wondered why can't we start an competition for chess.se too?

I think it may attract visitors and enthusiasts to keep us alive.

Comment: Interesting idea. Do you have a particular competition in mind?

Comment: @EdDean usually in other se sites they can conduct competitions based on votes but chess.se,my suggestions was to have a discussion in special chatroom for the competition,we can call all of the users whom were intrested and they can come with great ideas

Comment: I love the idea of playing postal chess with other users. The site could even have its own ranking system haha

Comment: about a blitz tournament on the SE lichess page? better be unrated or new users good at chess would mess with the rating system.